# How can ı pass function with state for react useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to learn how to use **react hooks**. I use **createContext** and I want to transfer together state and a function to other components, but I need help with how to do this. I also want to ask if it makes sense to do so.

In fact, I can update state by using **setState** in my case, but by defining a function in context, I think it makes more sense to use this function anywhere. Am I wrong ?

my context is :

```js
export const ExpenseContext = createContext();

export const ExpenseProvider = props => {
  const [expense, setExpense] = useState(initialExpenses)

  const clearItems = () => {
    setExpense([])
  }

  return ( <
    ExpenseContext.Provider value = {
      [expense, setExpense],
      clearItems
    } > {
      props.children
    } <
    /ExpenseContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

The component I want to use this function :

```js
const ExpenseList = () => {
  const [expense, setExpense] = useContext(ExpenseContext);
  const {
    clearItem
  } = useContext(ExpenseContext);

  //   const clearItems = () => { normally this works ı know! 
  //     setExpense([])
  // }

  return ( <
    >
    <
    List > {
      expense.map((expense) => {
        return <Item key = {
          expense.id
        }
        expense = {
          expense
        }
        />;
      })
    } <
    /List> <
    div className = "text-center" > {
      expense.length > 0 && ( <
        Button onClick = {
          clearItems
        }
        type = "danger"
        shape = "round"
        icon = { < DeleteOutlined / >
        } >
        Clear Expenses <
        /Button>
      )
    } <
    /div> < /
    >
  );
};
```

in this case, it is possible to use this function directly within the component without trying to transfer the function. But what I'm curious about is how I can manage to transfer and receive functions.

Note: when I try to use it in this way, I get this error: `TypeError: Object is not a function`

Comment: You’re in the right direction, but instead of storing them as an array, store them as property objects `const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(""); const value = {searchTerm, setSearchTerm };  <UserProvider value={value}>` and then use it like `const { searchTerm, setSearchTerm } = useContext(UserContext);`

Comment: I see your context value is not valid.

Comment: @ludwiguer thanks for the answer. I didn't understand how you sent the function into value.

Comment: @ridoansaleh so ? how do I make it functional ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The React Context is a mechanism for passing data through a React node tree without having to pass the props manually. The use of `createContext` creates a reference for a data structure within React's ecosystem that exposes a given data structure to the children nodes.

`Context.Provider` on the other hand provides a value to consuming components that are children nodes of the Provider. There are a few caveats to remember - whenever the properties of the value your provider is changing, it will trigger a re-render in all of its subscribers - it's descendants. The provider itself is not a hook, therefore when using hooks to generate values, you must re-render the provider with the new values set.

---

There are several things in your code that need to be addressed:

1. Using `useState` in a `Context.Provider`,
2. Returning the result of `useState` as the provider value, and
3. The structure of data provided as the value to provider

**Using `useState` in a `Context.Provider`**

When consuming the result of `useState` within a react `Context`, you have to be aware of the implications of consumption in descendants, and the impact that it will have. React is very good at determining what to re-render and when, and it provides you with control to limit that behavour even more. `useState` however, is a [react Functional Component Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) that *will* trigger a new render every time the value is updated. There are rules around this, precedence and delays, but you are guaranteed a re-render of whatever [Functional Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) consumes the `useState` hook. It's for this reason you want to treat your providers/context objects as pure functions where possible.

**Returning the result of `useState` as the provider value**

Within your example, you return the result of the `useState` call as-is to your context provider. This gives an object structure that React can't properly subscribe to and listen for changes.

**The structure of data provided as the value to provider**

When using state with your Provider, you need to return as proper JSON to the provider, so that that it can subscribe to value changes, and notify its descendants

Use

```
const providerValue = {
  expense,
  setExpense,
  clearItems
};
<ExpenseContext.Provider value={providerValue}/>
```

Instead of:

```
<ExpenseContext.Provider value = {
  [expense, setExpense],
  clearItems
} .../>
```

The object structure that you're providing the context provider is invalid. [See example codepen.](https://codepen.io/jmitchell38488/pen/mdVEMMx)

[Check out this great example on dev.to](https://dev.to/devdammak/react-hook-usestate-with-react-context-api-3pco) for `useState` with `Context`

Answer (score 3):

How I said in the comment you're very close, you pass functions, objects and values the same way

```
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState([]);
  const clearItems = () => {
    setExpenses([]);
  };
  const value = { expenses, setExpenses, clearItems };
```

Comment: codesandbox not found.